# Locking resources for an indeterminate amount of time

Tags: java, locking

My application contains a number of objects which contain getters and setters. These correspond to changing the state of physical objects (for example, a stepper motor).
Other threads may call methods on this object in order to do things to the stepper motor - this provides an interface between the stepper motor and the underlying hardware. So, for example, we may have a function that causes the motor to rotate by 15 degrees, or we may have a function that causes it to return to a neutral position.

Now, these objects care threadsafe, but that's not good enough. Consider the situation where one thread tries to rotate the motor by 90 degrees (by firing six calls to rotate by 15 degrees) and half way through, another resets the motor, meaning that it's only moved 45 degrees.

My design solution is to allow the controlling objects to take out locks on the controller, but I'm unsure how to manage this. It seems that most of the Java locking methods are designed to be atomic over a single method call, where I wish to have the objects locked for an indeterminate amount of time.

Would a simple Java lock be sufficient for this purpose, or does anyone know of something better? I'm worried by the fact that the standard ReentrantLock would seem to almost require the try-finally paradigm, meaning that I'd be likely bastardising it to a certain extent.

Comment: How do you know when the motor has finished rotating and can be sent another command, is it based on timing only?

Answer (score 1):

You could provide a method to submit several commands atomically. Assuming all your methods are synchronized, it could simply be:

```
public synchronized void submitAtomically(List<Command> commands) {
    for (Command c : commands) {
        submit(c);
    }
}

public synchronized void submit(Command c) {
    //rotate or reset or ...
}
```

If you don't want the methods to block other threads for too long, the simplest would be to use a typical producer/copnsumer pattern:

```
private final BlockingQueue<Command> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<> ();

public synchronized void submit(Command c) {
    queue.put(c);
}    

//somewhere else:

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            Command c = queue.take();
            c.execute();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

If a client submits 6 rotations via the `submitAtomically`, it prevents other threads from inserting other commands in the middle of the 6 rotations. However the `submit` operation is very fast (it does not actually execute the command) so it will not block the other threads for long.

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't quite work/isn't what I want. For example, one such higher level function may be: reset the lock to zero, and then every 3 minutes rotate by 360 degrees if a user presses a button. This would simply block the thread, which would not be useful. I could do it asynchronously, but that would be additional complexity.

Answer (score 0):

In the database world, this is done by having *transactions*, which is a way of grouping small low-level operations into big high-level operations that are atomic. Going down that road would be quite painful.

I think you need to go back and decide what the fundamental atomic operations are to be.

> Consider the situation where one thread tries to rotate the motor by 90 degrees (by firing six calls to rotate by 15 degrees) and half way through, another resets the motor, meaning that it's only moved 45 degrees.

It seems that you have decided that "rotate 15 degrees" is the only atomic operation, but that is evidently a poor fit for your application.

- Do you also need "rotate 45 degrees" and "rotate 90 degrees" as atomic operations? Perhaps you need "rotate *X* degrees" as an atomic operation?
- What is the purpose of rotating the motor to a particular position? If thread *A* rotates the motor to position *X*, and then thread *B* immediately rotates it to a different position, what has been achieved? Is some operation to be done (by thread *A*) once the motor is at position *X*? If so, you want the rotation *and* that operation together to be one atomic opeartion.
- And why rotate the motor by a given amount before performing an operation? Do you in fact want the motor to be in a specific position (absolute, not relative to its previous position) when the operation is performed? In that case you do not want your operations to be given the amount to rotate by, but rather the required position. The atomic operation would be responsible for deciding by how much to rotate the motor by.

Comment: I'm afraid I used the stepper motor as a simplistic example, because the device I'm actually working on is commercially sensitive (and nothing to do with stepper motors). Assume that my atomic operations are in fact as low level as I possibly can go, I was just trying to be illustrative. Obviously in real life with a stepper, you'd do it differently.